# Selecting from mySQL based on timeinterval

Tags: mysql

So... My brain has malfunctioned - the logic is gone and I'm frustrated!

I'm building a calender. I have a table with appointments:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | app_name  | app_start           | app_end             |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 3       | Meeting   | 2014-05-29 15:00:00 | 2014-05-29 17:00:00 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then the user can input a date and a time, and then a time interval.

Let's say the user selects 2014-05-29, 15:15 and sets the time interval to +2 hours.
This gives us two datetimes for comparison:

```
$start  =   '2014-05-29 15:15:00';
$end    =   '2014-05-29 17:15:00';
```

Now, I want to select all appointments in the calender which "conflict" with those two datetimes. However, appointments that end on $start should not be selected and appointments that starts on $end should not be selected.

Should be easy, but I haven't nailed it yet. The query I ended up with is this:

```
SELECT id, app_name
FROM appointments
WHERE user_id = ?
  AND ((app_start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_start != '$end')
  OR (app_end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end')
  OR (app_start > '$start' AND app_end > '$end'))
```

So what I'm asking is: How should my query look?

EDIT:

Based on answers to my question, the working query was this:

```
SELECT id, app_name FROM appointments 
WHERE user_id = ? 
  AND ((app_start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_start != '$end') 
  OR (app_end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_end != '$start') 
  OR (app_start < '$start' AND app_end > '$end'))
```

Comment: At first glance, you said, "However, appointments that end on $start should not be selected and appointments that starts on $end should not be selected." You can't use between as it includes matching times. You'll have to use something like `app_start < '$start' AND app_start <'$end' AND app_start != '$end'

Comment: Using BETWEEN is fine when it is combined with an extra statement (!=) :)

Comment: !duh... great retort. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict appointments should be one of the following

1. Appointment started in given time frame.

   (app_start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_start != '$end')
2. Appointment ended in given time frame.

   app_end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
3. Appointments started before this time and ended after the end time. In your condition you have used pp_start >   '$start'  bu tit was already covered in first condition. Now you are looking for appointments which were started before and ended after end time.

   (app_start <  '$start' AND app_end > '$end')

   SELECT id, app_name FROM appointments WHERE user_id = ? AND 
   ((app_start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_start != '$end') OR (app_end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end') OR (app_start <  '$start' AND app_end > '$end'))

Comment: Thank you! Although one condition was missing... app_end != '$start'. So the working query was:

SELECT id, app_name FROM appointments WHERE user_id = ? AND ((app_start BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_start != '$end') OR (app_end BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND app_end != '$start') OR (app_start < '$start' AND app_end > '$end'))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to find conflicting appointments:

```
SELECT id, app_name
FROM appointments
WHERE user_id = ?
  AND app_end > '$start'
  AND app_start < '$end'
```